# Search for a folder and and get the content of the files inside

Tags: php

I'm trying to search for a folder and retrieve the files inside of the folder (get content) I'm able to search for the folder using the follow code but I can't pass from there I can't see the content an retrieve the files inside. The files inside will be txt files and I would like to be able to open and see then.
How can achieve what i want?  Thank you.

```
 <?php   
$dirname = "C:\windows";//Directory to search in. *Must have a trailing slash*
$findme = $_POST["search"];

$dir = opendir($dirname);

while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))){//Loop for every item in the directory.
if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != ".DS_Store") and ($file !=
"search.php"))//Exclude these files from the search
{
$pos = stripos($file, $findme);
if ($pos !== false){
$thereisafile = true;//Tell the script something was found.
echo'<a href="' . $dirname . $file . '">' . $file . '</a><br>';
}else{

}
}
}
if (!isset($thereisafile)){
echo "Nothing was found.";//Tell the user nothing was found.
echo '<img src="yourimagehere.jpg"/>';//Display an image, when nothing was found.
}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: `&&` has precedence over `AND`, so you may want to use that instead.

Comment: `glob()` is a good option as well as the best named php function ever! Still waiting for `moist()`

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a recursive function for searching the directory. I hope it’ll solve your problem.

```
function scandir_r($dir){
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array(".", ".."));
$arr = array();
    foreach($files as $file){
    $arr[] = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
        if(is_dir($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)){
        $arr = array_merge($arr, scandir_r($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file));
        }
    }
return($arr);
}

$dirname = "C:\windows";
$findme = "/".preg_quote($_POST["search"], "/")."/";
$files = preg_grep($findme, scandir_r($dirname));
if(sizeof($files)){
    foreach($files as $file){
    $_file = $dirname.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
    echo "<a href=\"$_file\">$file</a><br/>";
    }
}
else{
echo "Nothing was found.";
echo "<img src=\"yourimagehere.jpg\"/>";
}
```

Comment: I have the same result just find the folder but I can't see the files in it

Answer (score 0):

**New code**

```
<?php   
$dirname = "C:\\Windows\\";//Directory to search in. *Must have a trailing slash*
$findme = 'maxlink'; //$_POST["search"];

$files = scandir($dirname);


foreach ($files AS $file)
{
    if ($file == '.' or $file == '..' or $file == '.DS_Store' or $file == 'search.php') continue;

    if (stripos($file, $findme) !== false)
    {
        $found = true;
        echo 'FOUND FILE <a href="' . $dirname . $file . '">' . $file . '</a><hr>';
        echo 'OPENING IT:<br>';
        echo file_get_contents($dirname . $file);
        echo '<hr>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not found: <a href="' . $dirname . $file . '">' . $file . '</a><br>';
    }
}

if (!isset($found))
{
    echo "Nothing was found.";//Tell the user nothing was found.
    echo '<img src="yourimagehere.jpg"/>';//Display an image, when nothing was found.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can search perfect the folder but I'm new in php and I want to be able to see the files inside the folder that I was searching for

Comment: @marcos You just need to echo file name in the empty ELSE you have.

Comment: @marcos Sorry, misunderstood you. You want to echo the contents of the 1 file you found (or all files at once) and exit the script?

Comment: I'm searching for a folder XXXX  inside C:\windows  and I want to echo the files inside folder XXXX